# Error en consulta entre PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Buenas noches.

No se porque la consulta no se ejecuta.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
</html>
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$grupo= $_POST['grupo'];

    //Sentencia y ejecución de la misma
//  $idns=count($_POST['idn']);
$i="1";
    if(isset($nota[$i])){
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($_POST['idn']); $i++) {
      $sentencia23=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
            $numero = mysqli_num_rows($sentencia23);
      $ii="1"; $nota="nota"; $idnota="idnota";
      While($resultado23=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia23)){
      $nota.''.$ii = $_POST[$nota.''.$ii][$i];
            $idnota.''.$ii = $_POST[$idnota.''.$ii][$i];

 $result = $conexion->query("UPDATE notas SET nota = \'$nota.''.$ii\' WHERE Idn = \''$idnota.''.$ii'\'")

$ii++; }
}

    //$promedio=$_POST['resultado'][$i];

}

    //Comprobación de la actualización
    if ($resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)) {
        echo "Los datos han sido actualizados satisfactoriamente.";
    } else {
        echo "Intente nuevamente, no se ha podido ejecutar la actualización.".$ejecucion->error;
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: te sale algún error? Cual de todas las consultas es la que no se ejecuta? por favor se más detallado en tu pregunta para poder tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: Prueba a sacar por pantalla `var_dump($sentencia23)` a ver si te devuelve registros la primera consulta, y así con las sucesivas para saber por donde puede ir el fallo.

Answer (score 0):

En este bucle (al cual además le falta un punto y coma al final de la sentencia de UPDATE);

```
 $ii="1"; $nota="nota"; $idnota="idnota";

 while($resultado23=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia23)){
      $nota.''.$ii = $_POST[$nota.''.$ii][$i];
      $idnota.''.$ii = $_POST[$idnota.''.$ii][$i];

      $result = $conexion->query("UPDATE notas SET nota = \'$nota.''.$ii\' WHERE Idn = \''$idnota.''.$ii'\'");
      $ii++; 
}
```

Estás asignando valores no a una variable sino a un string:

```
     'nota1' = $_POST[$nota.''.$ii][$i];
```

Lo que querrías hacer es generar una variable llamada `$nota1`

```
      // Defines la variable $nota1
      ${$nota.''.$ii} = $_POST[$nota.''.$ii][$i];
      // Defines la variable $idnota1
      ${$idnota.''.$ii} = $_POST[$idnota.''.$ii][$i];
```

Ahora yo me pregunto, si el único propósito de tu bucle es actualizar las notas, por qué no mejor simplemente redefines el valor de `$nota` y `$idnota` en cada iteración?

```
      $nota = $_POST[$nota.''.$ii][$i];
      $idnota = $_POST[$idnota.''.$ii][$i];
```

Finalmente, no es buena idea interpolar manualmente variables en tus consultas. Debieras usar una sentencia preparada y luego hacer un bind de los parámetros:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE notas SET nota = ? WHERE Idn = ?");

while($resultado23=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia23)){
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST[$nota.''.$ii][$i], $_POST[$idnota.''.$ii][$i]);
    $stmp->execute();
}
```

Preparas la sentencia una vez y luego la reutilizas. O mejor todavía, validando parámetros:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE notas SET nota = ? WHERE Idn = ?");
while($resultado23=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia23)){
    if(isset($_POST[$nota.''.$ii]) && isset($_POST[$nota.''.$ii][$i]) && isset($_POST[$idnota.''.$ii]) && isset($_POST[$idnota.''.$ii][$i]) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST[$nota.''.$ii][$i], $_POST[$idnota.''.$ii][$i]);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: No me da la consulta aún, dice "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: Usando cuál de las 4 sugerencias que te puse?

Comment: Agregue el punto y coma al bucle. Además, defini las variables como me propusiste. Y me sale el error Parse error: unexpected end oficina file

Comment: Me faltaba un } ya se lo puse. Pero aparece el siguiente error Notice: undefined variable: consulta

Comment: Además dice warning: mysqli::query() empty query

Comment: Notice: undefined varable: ejecucion.

Comment: Notice: trying yo get property of non-object. Todos esos errores aparecen

Comment: o cuál de las sugerencias es la que mejor me recomiendas?